# Is adding specific prestige classes tags necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags

It annoys me that there are no tags for specific prestige classes. I have recently added a tag for the dragon disciple class. I feel that we should add tags for all of the official prestige classes of every game, but I'm unsure if that is necessary or even a good idea. Should we add these tags?

Comment: Why is this question getting so many down votes, when it is asking something along the lines of this question that doesnt: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3346/is-it-worthwhile-to-add-a-roll20-tag-to-the-main-list

Comment: Voting on meta is different than on the main site, much more loose and opinion-y (and doesn't affect rep). But if I had to guess, it's because this Q argues for a course of action more strongly than that other one. When a meta Q is arguing for something, often people will voted it up/down directly based on agreement/disagreement, rather than wait for someone to submit an answer they can vote up/down.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Fair enough.

Answer (score 17):

**No**

Prestige classes for 3.5/Pathfinder are extremely specific. Tags that are too specific just clutter up the site without adding any real value. How many users are going to need to quickly access all questions related to the dragon disciple prestige class? How many questions would actually fall under that tag?

We already have the generalized [prestige-class](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prestige-class) tag. I feel that it is already doing everything that is necessary.

Comment: Totally agree. The prestige class tag is only used on 22 questions. That is less questions than the total number of prestige classes available in both dnd3.5 and pathfinder. Adding tags that would go unused seems pointless.